# creating flexible Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my WebApp I consume a wcf web service and in my example I consume a Method that returns more than 400 value type. In the first the WebApp will show two column in the View(Table)

```
           //Model
           public class OrdersviewModel
           {
             public int Articlenr { get; set; }
             public string ArticleName { get; set; }
           }
```

Later the user has the possibility that he can add or show up new column 
 Value,The Question is how would be the model??

Comment: Please rephrase your question; it is not very clear what you need.

Comment: Is your question, "How do I hold 400 instances of `OrdersviewModel`?"

Comment: @intrixius in the first i want to show just two value type but later i can show more than one values type

Comment: @Izzy in the first just 2 instances

Comment: @mohamad-al-ibrahim Ok, so have you tried having an `Article` class (for the `Nr` and `Name`) and then your `OrdersViewModel` contains a `List<Article>` ? It's difficult to see what you're trying to accomplish here, could you add more detail to your question?

Comment: @Izzy   Articlenr and ArticleName  are only properties . later i would like to show up new Value type fom the retuns value from the method  i need new propertiy in the model

Comment: Ok, so why don't you create your new value type (a `struct`) and then add it as a property to your viewmodel?

Comment: how will be the Model than how to do that,but my I have problem in the View how to show the Data in the tabel.

Comment: You could use dictionary with key value data instead fixed values

Comment: @OlegBondarenko thank you, but how  to implement that in the view too?

Comment: Are you thnking of creating a base class called OrdersViewModel and extending it, so class OrdersWithMoreDetails : OrdersViewModel

Comment: thank you @ Peter Marshall  in simpel way i want to create Open Model

Answer (score 0):

That is your model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{    
    public Dictionary<int, string> OrdersViewDictionary { get; set; }       
}
```

into the view you could use dictionary like that

```
  @model MyViewModel

<table class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>            
            <th>Index key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            @foreach (var pairData in Model.OrdersViewDictionary) {
                <tr>

                    <td>@pairData.Key</th>
                    <td>@pairData.Value</th>

                </tr>
            }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you ,this code for the DropDownList to get all the returns properties from the Method, but i want to show up the data in the Table

Comment: thank you  @Oleg Bondarenko in simpel way i want to create Open Model